# Why am I always getting a time difference of zero?

Tags: java, date, time, calendar

Why is this time difference always 0? Basically `start` and `end` have the same value always. I have tried using `Calendar` instead of `Date`. And if I use `Duration` instead of Date, I cannot compare `boolean temp = (diff>500);`.

```
private Date now=new Date();
private long start;
private long end;

public void ABC(){
   start = now.getTime();
   ...
   ...
   ...
   ...
   end = now.getTime();
   long diff = end - start;
   boolean temp = (diff>500);
   System.out.println(diff);  //This always outputs 0, basically start and end have same value always
}
```

Comment: because you are using the same date instance for start and end time. this could be the possible reason for 0 difference

Comment: You create _one_ `new Date()`. This stores the time it was created. Try creating _two_ `new Date()` at different times.

Comment: use : start= new Date().getTime() and end=new Date().getTime()

Comment: @akshayapandey easier: `start = System.currentTimeMillis(); end = System.currentTimeMillis();`.

Comment: FYI, you are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

Comment: By the way, if you are trying to do micro-benchmarks, I suggest using a test harness such as [JMH – Java Microbenchmark Harness](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-performance/jmh.html) proposed for  [addition to Java](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/230).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `Date` in Java has a default constructor which allocates a Date object and initializes it.
So in your code you have initialized the at the beginning as follows.

```
private Date now=new Date();
```

So every time you call the `now.getTime()` it will only return the value initialized at the start.

That means in your case both `start` and `end` will have the same value.

So always the dff will be 0

To avoid this you need to create new object of Date class:

```
start = new Date().getTime();
end = new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: Could be the possible reason, or is the reason? You seem quite unsure about it.

Comment: The use of just one `Date` object as in the question is *sure* to give you a difference of 0. On the other hand, for two `Date` objects to give you a greater difference, it is also required that they are created at two different times; if the code between the two instantiations executes in less than a millisecond, you will still have a difference of 0.

Answer (score 4):

Beacuse it's the same date. `now = new Date()` sets date to current date. `.getTime()` just converts date to `long`.

As I understand you want to get current date for both of the variables so you should use instead:

```
start = new Date().getTime();
end = new Date().getTime();
```

Comment: Easier: `start = System.currentTimeMillis(); end = System.currentTimeMillis();`. (And [it's equivalent](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Date.java#163)).

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can use `java.time.Duration` if you want.

```
    Instant start = Instant.now();
    // ...
    Instant end = Instant.now();
    Duration diff = Duration.between(start, end);
    boolean temp = diff.toMillis() > 500;
```

I agree with [Andy Turner’s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47388959/why-am-i-always-getting-a-time-difference-of-zero#comment81730883_47388959), though, for your purpose you need not instantiate any objects, `System.currentTimeMillis()` suffices.

Comment: In Java 9, a new `Clock` implementation may capture the current moment in a granularity finer than [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond). On a MacBook Pro, I am seeing [microseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond).

Comment: Another option for timing that will often be finer than milliseconds is `System.nanoTime()`. It won’t tell you the time of day or anything like that, but for the difference between `start` and `end` it works nicely (@BasilBourque, you knew this already, but for the OP and posterity).